# Display related products in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to display related products in javascript on eBay listing.
I have that idea: I keep in array info about other listings like: url, image, price and tags attached to this product.

example:

```
some_product = [
    tags: 'home, garden, kitchen',
    url: http://listing.url,
    price: 100
],
some_product_2 = [
    tags: 'home, lifestyle, books',
    url: http://listing2.url,
    price: 120
]
```

and on listing I put code like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://domain.com/related_prod.js?keyword=home"></script>
```

And I expect that showed all the products with "home" in "tags". Can someone direct me to a solution?

Comment: That's not valid JavaScript.

Comment: I'm not sure I really understood what your trying to do, but anyway, this smells a little bit like a job for a `JSON` file consumed using `AJAX`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, this is not a valid JavaScript or JSON:

```
some_product = [
  tags: 'home, garden, kitchen',
  url: http://listing.url,
  price: 100
],
  some_product_2 = [
  tags: 'home, lifestyle, books',
  url: http://listing2.url,
  price: 120
]
```

The above should be replaced with the `{ }` for objects.

```
{
    some_product: {
      tags: 'home, garden, kitchen',
      url: http://listing.url,
      price: 100
    },
      some_product_2: {
      tags: 'home, lifestyle, books',
      url: http://listing2.url,
      price: 120
    }
}
```

The above is a JavaScript object now. But this has been made better. Now, this being a pure JSON, it has to be added to a JavaScript variable. Consider this:

```
var products = {
    some_product: {
      tags: 'home, garden, kitchen',
      url: http://listing.url,
      price: 100
    },
      some_product_2: {
      tags: 'home, lifestyle, books',
      url: http://listing2.url,
      price: 120
    }
}
```

Now using the `products`, you can loop and put it as a list item.

```js
var products = {
  some_product: {
    tags: 'home, garden, kitchen',
    url: 'http://listing.url',
    price: 100
  },
  some_product_2: {
    tags: 'home, lifestyle, books',
    url: 'http://listing2.url',
    price: 120
  }
}
var finalHtml = "";
for (var item in products) {
  finalHtml += '<li><a href="' + products[item].url + '">' + item + '<\/a> <br \/>Tags: ' + products[item].tags + '<br \/>Price: ' + products[item].price + ' $</li>';
}
document.getElementById("products").innerHTML = finalHtml;
```

```html
<ul id="products"></ul>
```

See the snippet above.

Comment: I know, it was just a sketch. I hope everyone understood :)

But this display all products, not those with tag home.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that's not valid JavaScript, we can restructure your code to something more usable for your scenario...  Like this:

```
var products = [
  {
    name: 'some_product',
    tags: ['home', 'garden', 'kitchen'],
    url: 'http://example.com/1',
    price: 100,
  },

  {
    name: 'some_product_2',
    tags: ['home', 'lifestyle', 'books'],
    url: 'http://example.com/2',
    price: 120, 
  }
];
```

From here, we can use [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to fetch the results based on `tags`:

```
function category(tag) {
  return products.filter(function(product){
    if (~product.tags.indexOf(tag)) return product;
  });
}

category('home');
// ...
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/jdtmz7ua/1/)

Answer (score 0):

both Praveen Kumar and Jamen proved to be helpful. I joined their answers to create one code.

```js
var products = [
  {
    name: 'some_product',
    tags: ['home', 'garden', 'kitchen'],
    url: 'http://example.com/1',
    price: 100,
  },

  {
    name: 'some_product_2',
    tags: ['home', 'lifestyle', 'books'],
    url: 'http://example.com/2',
    price: 120, 
  },

  {
    name: 'some_product_3',
    tags: ['garden', 'lifestyle', 'books'],
    url: 'http://example.com/2',
    price: 120, 
  }
];

var finalHtml = "";

function category(tag) {
  return products.filter(function(product){
    if (~product.tags.indexOf(tag)) {
     finalHtml += '<li><a href="' + product.url + '">' + product.name + '<\/a><br \/>Price: ' + product.price + ' $</li>';
      document.getElementById("products").innerHTML = finalHtml;
     console.log(product.name);
    }
  });
}
category('home');
//category('garden');
```

```html
<ul id="products"></ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p5x2v2cb/

Thank you for answers.